# Getting "Closed connection" issue in Spring + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss

I am using **Spring** and **Hibernate** in my application. I am using **JBoss EAP 6.1** as my app server.

I have used **Spring** to create `sessionFactory` for **Hibernate** by following code :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                    <!-- list of annotatedClasses -->
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">$(hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto)</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

**Autowired** `sessionFactory` in my **Spring DAO** class as :

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

I have used `sessionFactory` as follows to get **Hibernate** `Session` :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query).addEntity(className);

    if (null != arg)
        sqlQuery.setParameters(arg, type);

    list = sqlQuery.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (HibernateException ex) {
    LOG.error(ex);
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
    throw ex;
}
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close();
```

As shown in above code, I have closed the Hibernate `Session` every time. Still I am getting Closed Connection issue after I run my application for about half an hour:

```
17:25:15,500 ERROR [org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) JDBC rollback failed: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3901) [ojdbc6.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcRollback(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:1010)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.rollback(WrappedConnection.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:217) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:196) [hibernate-core.jar:3.3.0.SP1]
    at com.ghcm.emailselection.db.DBOperations.selectRecordForBean(DBOperations.java:91) [classes:]
    at com.ghcm.emailselection.dao.UserSpecificDetailsDaoImpl.getUserInfo(UserSpecificDetailsDaoImpl.java:34) [classes:]
    at com.ghcm.emailselection.service.UserSpecificDetailsImpl.getUserInfo(UserSpecificDetailsImpl.java:32) [classes:]
    at com.ghcm.emailselection.dao.LoginDAOImpl.doLogin(LoginDAOImpl.java:97) [classes:]
    at com.ghcm.emailselection.service.LoginServiceImpl.doLogin(LoginServiceImpl.java:80) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196) [spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy195.doLogin(Unknown Source)    at com.ghcm.emailselection.controller.LoginController.dologin(LoginController.java:69) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) [spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ghcm.emailselection.controller.CustomAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CustomAuthenticationFilter.java:77) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at com.utxfrmwk.security.filter.SecurityInterceptor.doFilter(SecurityInterceptor.java:40) [UtxSecurityUtility.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
```

I am facing this issue frequently in about every half an hour. I need to fluch the JNDI pool or to restart JBOSS app server to solve it.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or what action should I take to resolve the "Closed Connection" issue?

Kindly help!

Comment: Try session.close() instead of sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close(). Doesn't make any sense

Comment: sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close() is not required , since you are using hibernate.current_session_context_class = thread , the session will be closed automatically when transaction commits or rolls back.Please try removing that

Comment: @Atul Initially I have not used the close() method and was getting same issue. An that's why I added the close() method line after the end of transaction.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate I tried with session.close(), but still was getting same result. Also session.close() was throwing an error where I am reading CURSOR from a procedure as ResultSet is closed.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate Getting this error while using session.close() : org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed :(

Comment: @gohil90 close session in finally block

Comment: @Rembo Tried in finally block also. No luck! :(

Comment: @gohil90 check if you set timeout option in hibernate, that causes may be the excption you getting

Comment: @Rembo which timeout you are talking about? and where should I define it?

Comment: @gohil90 in hibernate configuration

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48471/discussion-between-rembo-and-gohil90)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html) documentation of `ThreadLocalSessionContext` which you have configured by `<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>`

> In the interest of usability, it was decided to have this default impl actually generate a session upon first request and then clean it up after the Transaction associated with that session is committed/rolled-back

That means your session will be automatically closed when transaction either committed or rolled-back.

As I am assuming you are using spring for managing transactions,then it is never a good thing to set `hibernate.current_session_context_class`. By default spring will use [CurrentSessionContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/SpringSessionContext.html).

Now here you have used thread in current_session_context_class. Then for your own relish I would suggest

```
try{
    //... your code
} catch(HibernateException ex) {
    LOG.error(ex);
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
    throw ex;
} finally {
    if(session.isOpen()){ //I don't think this will return true in any case but still for your satisfaction you could do this
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

From the chat use following configuration in your spring datasource bean

```
<max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
<query-timeout>500</query-timeout>
```

Comment: Then why am I getting Closed Connection error after some time? :/

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting some ways to use session:

**using openSession()**:

openSession() opens a new session, that you have to close once you are done.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Transaction tx = null;
try {

    //get a transaction before performing any operations..
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    //perform your transaction here

    //commit the transaction as it is success.
    tx.commit();
} catch (HibernateException ex) {
    //rollback the current transaction, since a exception occurred, while performing transaction
    if(tx!=null)
      tx.rollback();
    throw ex;
}finally{

  //finally close the session, since transaction is completed.
  session.close();
}
```

---

**using getCurrentSession():**

As you have set in your hibernate configuration property `hibernate.current_session_context_class` to `thread` it means hibernate will close session autometically when a transaction completed.

```
//getCurrentSession() returns a session bound to a context, you don't need to close this
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Transaction tx = null;
    try {

        //get a transaction before performing any operations..
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        //perform your transaction here

        //commit the transaction as it is success.
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        //rollback the current transaction, since a exception occurred, while performing transaction
        if(tx!=null)
          tx.rollback();
        throw ex;
    }
```